# Arduino AccelStepper Library not reversing direction

Tags: arduino

I am running an Arduino Mega, LCD Sheild 1602, TB6600 Driver, Nema 17 motor.

Code: https://pastebin.com/6HGLhADF

The code for "running" works fine.

I have tried several different options (like setting negative value or moveTo) to "reset" the motor but when I select the reset menu item I want the motor to run in counter clockwise. the speed changes but the direction does not.

Can anyone help me understand why the motor is not running in reverse direction?

Code also Pasted below if needed: I used Paul Siewerts LCD tutorial as my base.

```
    Name    : LCD Button Shield Menu
    Author  : Paul Siewert
    Created : June 14, 2016
    Last Modified: June 14, 2016
    Version : 1.0
    Notes   : This code is for use with an Arduino Uno and LCD/button shield. The
              intent is for anyone to use this program to give them a starting
              program with a fully functional menu with minimal modifications
              required by the user.
    License : This program is free software. You can redistribute it and/or modify
              it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
              the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
              (at your option) any later version.
              This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
              but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
              MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
              GNU General Public License for more details.
 ***************************************************************************************/
/*
   This program is designed to get you as close as possible to a finished menu for the standard Arduino Uno LCD/button shield. The only required modifications
   are to add as menu items to the master menu (menuItems array) and then modify/adjust the void functions below for each of those selections.
*/
 
#include <AccelStepper.h> 
// defines pins numbers
  //Motor Pins
const int stepPin = 11; 
const int dirPin = 2; 
const int enPin = 13;
AccelStepper stepper(1,stepPin, dirPin, enPin);
 
// defines variables
int maxStepSpeed = 10000;
//long stepSpeed = 316.0299659;
//long stepResetSpeed = -1000;
//int forwarddir = 44802;
 
// You can have up to 10 menu items in the menuItems[] array below without having to change the base programming at all. Name them however you'd like. Beyond 10 items, you will have to add additional "cases" in the switch/case
// section of the operateMainMenu() function below. You will also have to add additional void functions (i.e. menuItem11, menuItem12, etc.) to the program.
String menuItems[] = {"Start", "Reset"};
 
// Navigation button variables
int readKey;
 
// Menu control variables
int menuPage = 0;
int maxMenuPages = round(((sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(String)) / 2) + .5);
int cursorPosition = 0;
 
// Creates 3 custom characters for the menu display
byte downArrow[8] = {
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b10101, // * * *
  0b01110, //  ***
  0b00100  //   *
};
 
byte upArrow[8] = {
  0b00100, //   *
  0b01110, //  ***
  0b10101, // * * *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100  //   *
};
 
byte menuCursor[8] = {
  B01000, //  *
  B00100, //   *
  B00010, //    *
  B00001, //     *
  B00010, //    *
  B00100, //   *
  B01000, //  *
  B00000  //
};
 
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
 
// Setting the LCD shields pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);
 
void setup() {
 
  // Initializes serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
 
  // Initializes and clears the LCD screen
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
 
  // Creates the byte for the 3 custom characters
  lcd.createChar(0, menuCursor);
  lcd.createChar(1, upArrow);
  lcd.createChar(2, downArrow);
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(maxStepSpeed);
//  stepper.setSpeed(stepSpeed);
//  stepper.moveTo(44803);
  stepper.disableOutputs();
}
 
void loop() {
  mainMenuDraw();
  drawCursor();
  operateMainMenu();
}
 
// This function will generate the 2 menu items that can fit on the screen. They will change as you scroll through your menu. Up and down arrows will indicate your current menu position.
void mainMenuDraw() {
  Serial.print(menuPage);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
  lcd.print(menuItems[menuPage]);
  lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
  lcd.print(menuItems[menuPage + 1]);
  if (menuPage == 0) {
    lcd.setCursor(15, 1);
    lcd.write(byte(2));
  } else if (menuPage > 0 and menuPage < maxMenuPages) {
    lcd.setCursor(15, 1);
    lcd.write(byte(2));
    lcd.setCursor(15, 0);
    lcd.write(byte(1));
  } else if (menuPage == maxMenuPages) {
    lcd.setCursor(15, 0);
    lcd.write(byte(1));
  }
}
 
// When called, this function will erase the current cursor and redraw it based on the cursorPosition and menuPage variables.
void drawCursor() {
  for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {     // Erases current cursor
    lcd.setCursor(0, x);
    lcd.print(" ");
  }
 
  // The menu is set up to be progressive (menuPage 0 = Item 1 & Item 2, menuPage 1 = Item 2 & Item 3, menuPage 2 = Item 3 & Item 4), so
  // in order to determine where the cursor should be you need to see if you are at an odd or even menu page and an odd or even cursor position.
  if (menuPage % 2 == 0) {
    if (cursorPosition % 2 == 0) {  // If the menu page is even and the cursor position is even that means the cursor should be on line 1
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.write(byte(0));
    }
    if (cursorPosition % 2 != 0) {  // If the menu page is even and the cursor position is odd that means the cursor should be on line 2
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.write(byte(0));
    }
  }
  if (menuPage % 2 != 0) {
    if (cursorPosition % 2 == 0) {  // If the menu page is odd and the cursor position is even that means the cursor should be on line 2
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.write(byte(0));
    }
    if (cursorPosition % 2 != 0) {  // If the menu page is odd and the cursor position is odd that means the cursor should be on line 1
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.write(byte(0));
    }
  }
}
 
 
void operateMainMenu() {
  int activeButton = 0;
  while (activeButton == 0) {
    int button;
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    if (readKey < 790) {
      delay(100);
      readKey = analogRead(0);
    }
    button = evaluateButton(readKey);
    switch (button) {
      case 0: // When button returns as 0 there is no action taken
        break;
      case 1:  // This case will execute if the "forward" button is pressed
        button = 0;
        switch (cursorPosition) { // The case that is selected here is dependent on which menu page you are on and where the cursor is.
          case 0:
            menuItem1();
            break;
          case 1:
            menuItem2();
            break;
        }
        activeButton = 1;
        mainMenuDraw();
        drawCursor();
        break;
      case 2:
        button = 0;
        if (menuPage == 0) {
          cursorPosition = cursorPosition - 1;
          cursorPosition = constrain(cursorPosition, 0, ((sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(String)) - 1));
        }
        if (menuPage % 2 == 0 and cursorPosition % 2 == 0) {
          menuPage = menuPage - 1;
          menuPage = constrain(menuPage, 0, maxMenuPages);
        }
 
        if (menuPage % 2 != 0 and cursorPosition % 2 != 0) {
          menuPage = menuPage - 1;
          menuPage = constrain(menuPage, 0, maxMenuPages);
        }
 
        cursorPosition = cursorPosition - 1;
        cursorPosition = constrain(cursorPosition, 0, ((sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(String)) - 1));
 
        mainMenuDraw();
        drawCursor();
        activeButton = 1;
        break;
      case 3:
        button = 0;
        if (menuPage % 2 == 0 and cursorPosition % 2 != 0) {
          menuPage = menuPage + 1;
          menuPage = constrain(menuPage, 0, maxMenuPages);
        }
 
        if (menuPage % 2 != 0 and cursorPosition % 2 == 0) {
          menuPage = menuPage + 1;
          menuPage = constrain(menuPage, 0, maxMenuPages);
        }
 
        cursorPosition = cursorPosition + 1;
        cursorPosition = constrain(cursorPosition, 0, ((sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(String)) - 1));
        mainMenuDraw();
        drawCursor();
        activeButton = 1;
        break;
    }
  }
}
 
// This function is called whenever a button press is evaluated. The LCD shield works by observing a voltage drop across the buttons all hooked up to A0.
int evaluateButton(int x) {
  int result = 0;
  if (x < 60) {
    result = 1; // right
  } else if (x < 300) {
    result = 2; // up
  } else if (x < 500) {
    result = 3; // down
  } else if (x < 700) {
    result = 4; // left
  }
  return result;
}
 
// If there are common usage instructions on more than 1 of your menu items you can call this function from the sub
// menus to make things a little more simplified. If you don't have common instructions or verbage on multiple menus
// I would just delete this void. You must also delete the drawInstructions()function calls from your sub menu functions.
void drawInstructions() {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1); // Set cursor to the bottom line
  lcd.print("Use ");
  lcd.print(byte(1)); // Up arrow
  lcd.print("/");
  lcd.print(byte(2)); // Down arrow
  lcd.print(" buttons");
}
 
void menuItem1() { // Function executes when you select the 1st item from main menu
  int activeButton = 0;
 
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
  lcd.print("running");
  long stepSpeed = 316.0299659;
  stepper.setSpeed(stepSpeed);
  
  while (activeButton == 0) {
    stepper.runSpeed();
    int button;
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    if (readKey < 790) {
      delay(100);
      readKey = analogRead(0);
    }
    button = evaluateButton(readKey);
    switch (button) {
      case 4:  // This case will execute if the "back" button is pressed
        button = 0;
        activeButton = 1;
        break;
    }
  }
}
 
void menuItem2() { // Function executes when you select the 2nd item from main menu
  int activeButton = 0;
 
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
  lcd.print("resetting");
  long stepSpeed = -1000;
  stepper.setSpeed(stepSpeed);
 
  while (activeButton == 0) {
    stepper.runSpeed();
    int button;
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    if (readKey < 790) {
      delay(100);
      readKey = analogRead(0);
    }
    button = evaluateButton(readKey);
    switch (button) {
      case 4:  // This case will execute if the "back" button is pressed
        button = 0;
        activeButton = 1;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [AccelStepper API](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/classAccelStepper.html#aa4a6bdf99f698284faaeb5542b0b7514), the first parameter for the constructor is the motor type. You have specified "1" which means **DRIVER**.  In this case, the enum for DRIVER says "Stepper Driver, 2 driver pins required."  and the constructor description says "AccelStepper::DRIVER (1) means a stepper driver (with Step and Direction pins). If an enable line is also needed, ***call setEnablePin() after construction***."

So my conclusion is that you're probably setting up the stepper incorrectly. Unless the documentation I linked to is wrong, you are incorrectly passing the enable pin as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am really new to programming an arduino, could you help me correct the code.

Comment: I don't have any of your devices. My only guess at the moment is to 
1) Replace the stepper motor object line (beginning of your code) with: AccelStepper stepper(1,stepPin, dirPin); and
2) Add stepper.setEnablePin(enPin); to your setup()
3) Optionally, make use of stepper.enableOutputs(); and stepper.disableOutputs() to activate/deactivate your outputs

Comment: I figured it out, it was actually me mistyping something in. I had the wrong pin set for the directional pin. it was supposed to be pin 12 not 2